# Angular custom theme - SassError: $map: null is not a map

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have created the following custom theme for my angular project:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */


@include mat.core();

$f-brand: (
  50 : #e0f2f1,
  100 : #b3e0db,
  200 : #80cbc4,
  300 : #4db6ac,
  400 : #26a69a,
  500 : #009688,
  600 : #008e80,
  700 : #008375,
  800 : #00796b,
  900 : #006858,
  A100 : #97ffec,
  A200 : #64ffe3,
  A400 : #31ffda,
  A700 : #18ffd5,
  contrast: (
    50 : #000000,
    100 : #000000,
    200 : #000000,
    300 : #000000,
    400 : #ffffff,
    500 : #ffffff,
    600 : #ffffff,
    700 : #ffffff,
    800 : #ffffff,
    900 : #ffffff,
    A100 : #000000,
    A200 : #000000,
    A400 : #000000,
    A700 : #000000,
  )
);

$primary: mat.define-palette($f-brand);

$theme: mat.define-light-theme($primary);

@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

I have also added the custom theme to my general styles.css file but when I run "ng serve" I get the following error:

```
SassError: $map: null is not a map.
  ╷
9 │   $foreground-base: map.get($foreground, base);
  │                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\ripple\_ripple-theme.scss 9:21  color()
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\ripple\_ripple-theme.scss 30:7  @content
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\_theming.scss 376:3     private-check-duplicate-theme-styles()
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\ripple\_ripple-theme.scss 27:3  theme()
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\_core-theme.scss 48:5           @content
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\_theming.scss 376:3     private-check-duplicate-theme-styles()
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\_core-theme.scss 47:3           theme()
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\_all-theme.scss 43:5    @content
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\_theming.scss 376:3     private-check-duplicate-theme-styles()
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\_all-theme.scss 42:3    all-component-themes()
  src\styles-f-theme.scss 44:1                                        root stylesheet
```

By searching the web I found out that "map.get" seems now to be "map-get". Unfortunately I don't have a clue how to fix this.

The Angular version used in my project is "14.0.5" and Angular Material version is "14.0.4",

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this error, because to construct a theme, 2 palettes are required: primary and accent.

Add new palette or set your primary as accent:

```
    $theme: mat.define-light-theme($primary, $primary);
```